# qtip live() support

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm loading a section of my page with a jQuery AJAX call and want to use qTips within that section.  Normally when loading jQuery functions through AJAX you use the `.live()` function.  Is there a way to attach a qTip using `.live()` or is there a qTip equivalent?

I've heard that qTip 2.0 will have this support but I don't believe 2.0 is ready yet.

Does anyone out there have a workaround?

Below is the full code that I believe should work but doesn't seem to:

```
$('.editquestion').live('click', function() {
                $(this).qtip({
                    overwrite:false,
                    content: {
                        url: $(this).attr('href'),
                        data: { id: 5 },
                        method: 'get',
                        title: {
                            text: 'Edit Question',
                            button: 'Close'
                         },
                         cache: false,
                    },
                    position: {
                        target: $(document.body), // Position it via the document body...
                        corner: 'center' // ...at the center of the viewport
                    },
                    show: {
                        ready:true,
                    },
                    hide: false,
                    style: {
                        width: { 
                            max: 550,
                            min: 550
                        },
                        height: {
                            max: 300,
                            min:300
                        },
                        padding: '14px',
                        border: {
                            width: 9,
                            radius: 9,
                            color: '#666666'
                        },
                        name: 'light'
                    },
                    api: {
                        beforeShow: function() {
                            // Fade in the modal "blanket" using the defined show speed
                            $('#qtip-blanket').fadeIn(this.options.show.effect.length);
                        },
                        beforeHide: function() {
                            // Fade out the modal "blanket" using the defined hide speed
                            $('#qtip-blanket').fadeOut(this.options.hide.effect.length);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Edit: Maybe I should also mention that the qtip uses ajax to load a form.

Answer (score 2):

see these two links

[Problem with qTip - Tips not showing because elements load after the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005521/problem-with-qtip-tips-not-showing-because-elements-load-after-the-script)

[jQuery dynamic qtip shows div, but gets slower and slower with every mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133215/jquery-dynamic-qtip-shows-div-but-gets-slower-and-slower-with-every-mouseover)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response.  The first link is one that I've seen.  It makes sense to me and logically should work but doesn't seem to.  It acts as if it's creating copies of itself.  Everytime I call up a qTip it makes more calls (eg, fist time: 1, second time: 2, etc).  The second link doesn't make much sense to me.  Isn't that pretty much the normal way you attach qtips on a static page?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the qtip when loading the new portion of the page, not on click.

You can also try checking to see if the qtip is already attached to the clicked object before attaching on click. Firebug will tell you what to check for.